# Proving Kummer's Transformation

Tags: transformation, hypergeometric-function

I'm working with a Kummer equation of the form:

$z\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial z^2}+(b-z)\frac{\partial w}{\partial z} -aw=0,$

which is solved by Kummer's Confluent Hypergeometric function:

${}_{1}F_{1}(a,b,z)=M(a,b,z).$

There is an identity, called Kummer's transformation, which states that:

$M(a,b,z)=e^{z}M(b-a,b,-z).$

I can currently prove this using the integral form of Kummer's equation:

$M(a,b,z)=\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b-a)\Gamma(a)}\int\limits_{0}^{1}e^{zt}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-a-1}\mathrm{d}t \text{,   for }b>a>0.$

But this is only valid under the conditions $b>a>0$. I have not found any source that quotes these same conditions for the transformation so I assume it can be proved by some other means. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Hamzaan

Comment: Here is a quote from N.N. Lebedev, Special Functions and Their Applications (adjusted to your variables):

"The relation [...] was proved under the assumption that $\Re b > \Re(b-a) > 0,$ but after dividing by $\Gamma(b)$, both sides become entire functions of $a$ and $b$. Therefore, according to the principle of analytic continuation, [...] remains valid for arbitrary $a$ and $b$, provided that $b \ne 0,-1,-2,\cdots$."

Comment: Thank you very much Gammatester. I'll have a look at the book you've quoted. This is very interesting because one of the solutions of Kummer's equation is given by $z^{1-b}M(1+a-b,2-b,z)$, which transforms to $z^{1-b}e^{z}M(1-a,2-b,-z)$, that will tend to give $2-b=0,-1,-2...$ if in the original equation b is integer greater than or equal to 2. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Use Chu-Vandermonde formula:
$$
\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(-n)_k(a)_k}{k!(b)_k}=\frac{(b-a)_n}{(b)_n},
$$
which can be derived from 
$$
{n+b \choose a}=\sum_{k=0}^a {n \choose k}{b\choose a-k}.
$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1012769)

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I don't understand why this does not answer the question. I mean, it might not be a *good* answer (I hold no opinion here) but it is at least *attempting* to answer the question, no?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Maybe I should say it is a hint rather than an answer. But to get the answer, it only need to compare the coefficients of z^n/n! of M(a,b,z) and e^{-z}M(b-a,a,-z) than you will find they are exactly the same by the Chu-Vandermonde formula I mentioned here.